# Add Web Reference prompts for credentials with "Discovery Credential" dialog but won't accept valid credentials

Tags: asp.net, web-services, reporting-services, credentials, reportingservices-2005

I'm attempting to add a web reference to my ASP.Net 3.0 project. This is a reference to the SQL Server Reporting Services web service. I have verified the service is up and running, but when I try to add the web reference in my project, I am prompted for my credentials, which I enter, and then prompted again and again and again. I have to hit cancel to stop the vicious cycle. When I do that the service definition comes up in the window, but the "Add Reference" button is disabled so I can't add the reference to my project.

I have limited knowledge of SQL Reporting Services configurations. If anyone knows how to resolve this problem I'd really appreicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to this code after a long weekend and it just mysteriously worked this time. No prompts to reference the web service. This leads me to think that some configuration on the server was changed and/or the server was rebooted. Not sure that this actually explains anything.